# generate waves from .caf using ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, waveform, caf

Actually I am trying to generate waves from .caf file. Is it possible? If yes, then can anyone tell me how can I generate the waves? I searched for it but I get demo which generates the waves from mp3, not from .caf. So, now can anyone suggest me for that?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this Code may be you get your problem solution

> `https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/cocoa-waveform`